# Mapstruct: BeforeMapping not called correctly

Tags: kotlin, mapstruct

I have the below mapper where i used the `BeforeMapping` annotation

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring", unmappedTargetPolicy = ReportingPolicy.IGNORE)
interface PaymentMapper {

    companion object {
        @JvmStatic
        @BeforeMapping
        fun mapInvoices(@MappingTarget target: Payment, source: PaymentRequested) {
            target.setbillerAuthIds(source.invoices.map { it.billerAuthId })
        }
    }
    
    fun permissionCreatedToPermission(source: PaymentRequested): Payment

}
```

The problem is in the implementation, the method `mapInvoices` is called in the end of the method

**Implementation**

```
@Component
public class PaymentMapperImpl implements PaymentMapper {

    @Override
    public Payment permissionCreatedToPermission(PaymentRequested source) {
        if ( source == null ) {
            return null;
        }

        String requestNumber = source.getRequestNumber();
        List<String> billerAuthIds = null;

        Payment payment = new Payment( requestNumber, billerAuthIds);

        PaymentMapper.mapInvoices( payment, source );

        return payment;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The method is called in the right place, before the setters are invoked (in your case there are no setters).

You have a before mapping that needs to have the mapping target `Payment` passed to it. However, the `Payment` has a constructor that MapStruct has to invoke in order to create an instance to pass to the lifecycle method.

If you want to map the `billerAuthIds` in a special way I would suggest that you provide a mapping method for them. MapStruct will then use that.